# Stupid conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

OK, so my knowledge of probability theory sucks and I'm trying to figure out how to justify this theoretically. Assume we have random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and a random variable $I$ with values in $\{1,...,n\}$. Then intuitively

$$\mathbb{P}[X_I=x\mid I=i] = \mathbb{P}[X_i = x].$$

How do I justify this from the definition

$$\mathbb{P}[A\mid B] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}?$$

Comment: Can't you justify this by substitution?

Comment: Yes, but how do you justify that you can just substitute? What are the event sets $A$ and $B$, so you can compute their intersection?

Comment: Just to mention that the accepted answer uses crucially the hypothesis that $I$ is independent of each $X_i$, something which is not in the question. Random variables such as $X_I$ often arise in contexts where this independence does *not* hold. But if independence is assumed in your question, then everything is allright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb P(X_I=x\mid I=i)
 & = \frac{\mathbb P(X_I=x\cap I=i)}{\mathbb P(I=i)}
 & \text{by definition}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathbb P(X_i=x\cap I=i)}{\mathbb P(I=i)}
 & (X_I=x\cap I=i) \equiv (X_i=x\cap I=i)
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{\mathbb P(X_i=x)\mathbb P(I=i)}{\mathbb P(I=i)}
 & \text{by independence}
\\[1ex]
& = \mathbb P(X_i=x) & \text{cancelling common terms in the quotient}
\end{align}$$

So your intuition served you well.

---

We *could* define sets of outcomes ($\omega$) in the probability space $\Omega$ for the real valued random variables $X_1, \ldots X_n$ and $I$ such that 
$$\begin{align}
A & \equiv \left\{\omega \mid \bigvee_{k=1}^n (X_k(\omega)=x\wedge I(\omega)=k)\right\}
\\ & \equiv \bigcup_{k=1}^n \left\{\omega \mid X_k(\omega)=x\wedge I(\omega)=k\right\}
\\[2ex]
B & \equiv \{\omega \mid I(\omega)=i\}
\\[2ex]
\therefore A\cap B & \equiv \{\omega\mid X_i(\omega)=x\wedge I(\omega)=i\}
\end{align}$$

But the more compact notation is generally understood; that the probability of random values being a certain value, or a range of values, is the probability measure of the set of outcomes where such happens.

That is, for instance, $\mathbb P(I=i) = \mathbb P(\{\omega\mid I(\omega)=i\})$.

Comment: After having done measure theory, I seem to get more and more confused about trivial probability issues, since the total space is never explicitly given as a concrete set... Even in this case the intersected sets are never concretely given, but I'm fine with this level of lack of rigour. :)

Comment: Even though I already accepted, you don't happen to know how to express the sets concretely, assuming that each $X_i$ is valued in some set $B$?